# RecyclerView клик при смене позиции

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-on-click, setonclicklistener

Без интерфейса все работало. Переделываю OnItemClickListener через интерфейс, и все работает до тех пор , пока не сбивается порядок айтемов при сортировке, например при поиске 20 я позиция становится первой и обрабатывается как первая.. 5 позиция становится на 1 место но обрабатывается как 1. Как правильно привязать ID в данном случае?

вот интерфейс:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

вот адаптер:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}

вот сам фрагмент:

public class Fragment_1extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,OnItemClickListener

adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(context, Detai.class);
        i.putExtra("pos2", StationList.get(position).getDetails_new());
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

и вот класс

```
public class ItemBusStation implements Serializable {

    private String details1;

    public ItemBusStation(
                   String details1) {
        this.details1 = details1;
    }

    public String getDetails1() {
        return details1;
    }
```

Comment: для данных нужно использовать уникальный идентификатор, а не позицию в списке . Если это БД, то брать непосредственно из БД, если другой тип постоянного хранилища, добавить самому.

Comment: Может быть есть какой то пример или где почитать об этом для того что бы правильно сделать. Данные хранятся в файле json на устройстве

Comment: И второй вопрос почему не сбивается при поиске позиция если делаю клик не через интерфейс